# In Snowflake query an array of objects but only select some of the attributes of that object

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have a table

`mytable`

`email VARCHAR` 
`myarray ARRAY`

Suppose this Array is an array of Objects and each object has attributes labeled 'a' through 'f'.

What is the proper syntax to select the email and myarray but only select object attributes 'a' through 'd' and 'f', bypassing attribute 'e' ?  The output should also be a VARCHAR and an Array (of Objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
select 
i.path, i.value::string object_keys_values
from 
cte , lateral flatten(input=>myarray) j , lateral flatten(input=>j.value) i  
where i.path <>'e';

cte2 as (select  
   object_agg(i.path, i.value::variant)  obj
from cte , lateral flatten(input=>myarray) j , lateral flatten(input=>j.value) i where i.path <>'e' 
group by  j.value)
select array_agg(obj) final_array from cte2
```

[image]

[image]

```
with cte as ( select 'john.doe@email.com'  email, 
           [     object_construct('a',1,'b','BBBB', 'c','sheep','d',1,'e','BBBB', 'f','kumera')  
               , object_construct('a',10,'b','BBBB', 'c','kiora','d',10,'e','BBBB', 'f','pavalova')
               , object_construct('a',100,'b','BBBB', 'c','gidday','d',100,'e','BBBB', 'f','kiwifruit')
           ] myarray )
 select  * from cte ;
```

ALTERNATIVE APPROACH -> KEEPING ORDER IN SYNC

[image]

```
    with cte as ( select 'john.doe@email.com'  email, 
       [     object_construct('a',1,'b','BBBB', 'c','sheep','d',1,'e','BBBB', 'f','kumera')  
           , object_construct('a',10,'b','BBBB', 'c','kiora','d',10,'e','BBBB', 'f','pavalova')
           , object_construct('a',100,'b','BBBB', 'c','gidday','d',100,'e','BBBB', 'f','kiwifruit')
       ] myarray )
       
 SELECT EMAIL, ARRAY_AGG( OBJECT_DELETE(j.value, 'e' )) from cte, 
lateral flatten(input=>myarray) j GROUP BY EMAIL;
```

Comment: How to output the email plus the modified array?

Comment: In addition, final_array should maintain the order of the original array's objects.  The missing attribute was used to get them into the right sort order.

Comment: select array_agg(obj) final_array from cte2 . You can order the array_agg() using within group option.  If the order is random - let me know and I will delete this answer

Comment: I am having some trouble here because the initial array is ordered correctly based on the value of the attribute 'e' in descending order.  When I try various things to drop that attribute, the sort order gets disturbed.

Comment: @ Mark G - Added Alternative Solution.  Keeping the order in sync.  Asking clear questions from the outset demonstrates clear thought process.